# Как к своей динамической библиотеке подключить еще одну динамическую библиотеку?

Tags: cmake, library

У меня есть собранная динамическая библиотека. Мне надо ее подключить в другую динамическую библиотеку, которую я буду собирать. Как это можно сделать?
До этого у меня был проект с main, где я подключала библиотеку. А теперь надо ее подключить в библиотеку.

Comment: `LoadLibrary()` загружает библиотеки в пространство процессов

Comment: @PRODIGY, это если на рантайме загружать ее, а если в cmake то просто к той динамической библиотеке написать target_link_library